# I am having trouble identifying this bike logo

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]I came across this bike recently and can't figure out what it is. I've Google lensed it, I've searched the serial number and still nothing. Please help, it's driving me crazy! I know it's a 24inch XL Pro bmx but that's it...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a RAZOR. But impossible to tell with just one picture

Comment: Welcome to the site - Good lead, but googling up "razor bmx logo" returns a lot of circular saw-blade like images, eg  https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/al-na-9d5791cf-3faf/83fc37c5-0f7b-403f-869c-96542b1e57ac._RO199,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15_FMpng_.jpg   Have you got any more information on why you think it might be razor ?

Comment: Also, Razor seems to be a sub brand of Polygon now, so it might be an older logo too.